# How can I write a command in multiple lines in R?

Tags: r

I code in Python and JS on a daily basis and readability of my code is very important to me and my team. Is there any way to make a long command more readable in R? For example:

```
onTimeData <- origData[!is.na(origData$ARR_DEL15) & 
                         origData$ARR_DEL15!="" & 
                         !is.na(origData$DEP_DEL15) & 
                         origData$DEP_DEL15!="",]
```

This produces `Error: unexpected ',' in "origData$DEP_DEL15!="","`

Is there some way I can write it in multiple lines in RStudio?

Comment: Not reproducible. I defined `origData<-data.frame(ARR_DEL15=letters,DEP_DEL15=LETTERS, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`, run your code and received no error.

Comment: using `with()` or `subset()` (see caveats elsewhere on SO) or the `dplyr` tools recommended in an answer below will also help readability

Comment: I write code that looks like that all the time. It should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

What you have should work just fine. All you missed was the `which()` function which will return the rows that match all your requirements.

```
onTimeData <- origData[which(!is.na(origData$ARR_DEL15) & 
                     origData$ARR_DEL15!="" & 
                     !is.na(origData$DEP_DEL15) & 
                     origData$DEP_DEL15!=""),]
```

Comment: Why do you think you need which here?

Comment: Thanks! That works perfect. Code without which() runs fine in one line but not in multiple lines. Using which() it runs fine both ways. Is it because you need which() to 'tell' R that it is still the same command on all 4 lines since it's encapsulated in parentheses?

Answer (score 0):

Since readability is a priority, I would suggest you examine the `dplyr` package.  It essentially gives you a functional programming type approach to data manipulation.  Consequently, I feel the code is much more readable.  For example

```
library(dplyr)
onTimeData <-
 origData %>%
     filter(!is.na(ARR_DEL15) & 
       ARR_DEL15!="" & 
       !is.na(DEP_DEL15) & 
       DEP_DEL15!="")
```

I find this much prettier.  No need to make numerous annoying calls to the `'$'` function.

Comment: or see `with()` or `subset()` in base R.